# How to create a dynamic Reference in node js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am developing a nodejs program and I am facing a problem, I have a mongo schema that is a list of objects :

```
players: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
```

But this ref: 'User' isnt enough for what I need. This "players" have the possibility to recieve the object 'User' or the object 'Team' for example. But how can I declare it? Should I delete the "ref" parameter?

One information is: If I put one "User" on this players attributes, I will not put any other type, all objects will be users, the same thing for "Team". But I will know if will be list of teams or list of users, at the time I will create the object.

So how can I declare it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
    const documentSchema = new Schema({
      referencedAttributeId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: 'onModel'
       },
      onModel: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Collection1', 'Collection2']
      }
    });
```

Now this collection has attribute named referencedAttributeId which links to two collections ('Collection1', 'Collection2'). Whenever you use .populate() function, mongoose will automatically get referenced data.

```
const data = await CollectionName.find().populate('referencedAttributeId','attributeName1 attributeName2')
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mongoose` supports [dynamic references](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref). You specify the type with a `String` and a `refPath`. Take a look at the example of schema provided by the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref):

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  connections: [{
    kind: String,
    item: { type: ObjectId, refPath: 'connections.kind' }
  }]
});
```

> The refPath property above means that mongoose will look at the
>   connections.kind path to determine which model to use for populate().
>   In other words, the refPath property enables you to make the ref
>   property dynamic.

An example, from the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref), of `populate` call:

```js
// Say we have one organization:
// `{ _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000001'), name: "Guns N' Roses", kind: 'Band' }`
// And two users:
// {
//   _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000002')
//   name: 'Axl Rose',
//   connections: [
//     { kind: 'User', item: ObjectId('000000000000000000000003') },
//     { kind: 'Organization', item: ObjectId('000000000000000000000001') }
//   ]
// },
// {
//   _id: ObjectId('000000000000000000000003')
//   name: 'Slash',
//   connections: []
// }

User.
  findOne({ name: 'Axl Rose' }).
  populate('connections.item').
  exec(function(error, doc) {
    // doc.connections[0].item is a User doc
    // doc.connections[1].item is an Organization doc
  });
```